# Complex (for me) QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have an odd relationship.

3 classes: Manager, Group, Vehicle

Group has a many to many to both Manager and Vehicle, but neither Manager nor Vehicle know anything about Group (only a one way mapping).

I have a ManagerID. I want to get a distinct list items of type T that has a VehicleID that is in a group that has a manager with the specified ID.

```
var vehicles = Session.QueryOver<Group>(() => group)
                .Right.JoinQueryOver<Manager>(x => x.Managers)
                .Where(x => x.Id == managerID)
                .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property<VehicleGroup>(g => g.Vehicles)))
                .List<Vehicle>()
                ;
```

Now what?

Ok, some further information:
"Manager" is not mapped to groups.
"Vehicle" is not mapped to groups.
Group has many Managers
Group has many Vehicles
A Manager can be referenced by multiple groups.
A Vehicle can be managed by multiple groups.

I have a Manager ID.  I want to get a list of distinct Vehicle from the groups that have that manager.

============================================

Ok.  More:
SQL I wish to emulate:

```
        select * from Summary
        where [vehicleID] in
        (
          select [vehicleID] from [Managers] 
            inner join [Manager_Groups] on [Managers].[managerID] = [Manager_Groups].[managerID]
            inner join [Groups] on [Manager_Groups].[groupID] = [Groups].[groupID]
            inner join [Groups_Object] on [Groups].[groupID] = [Groups_Object].[groupID]
            inner join [Vehicle] on [Groups_Object].[ID] = [Vehicle].[vehicleId]
          where [Managers].[ManagerId] = 34 and [Groups].[type] = 1
        )
```

There are 2 types of groups. Drivers (type = 0) and vehicles (type = 1)

So far, I have:

```
var sq = QueryOver.Of<Manager>(() => manager)
    .Where(mf => mf.Id == managerId)
    .Fetch(mf => mf.ManagedVehicleGroups).Eager
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity) 
    .JoinQueryOver<VehicleGroup>(mf => mf.ManagedVehicleGroups)
    .SelectList(list => list.Select(mf => mf.ManagedVehicleGroups))
    ;

var vp = Session.QueryOver<VehiclePerformanceDay>(() => item)
    .WithSubquery.WhereExists(sq)
    .Take(10)
    .List();
```

And this generates:

```
SELECT
    TOP (10) this_. ~~~lots of fields removed~~~
FROM
    dbo.Summary this_ 
WHERE
    exists (
        SELECT
            this_0_.ManagerId as y0_ 
        FROM
            dbo.Managers this_0_ 
        inner join
            dbo.Manager_Groups managedveh3_ 
                on this_0_.ManagerId=managedveh3_.managerID 
        inner join
            dbo.Groups vehiclegro1_ 
                on managedveh3_.groupID=vehiclegro1_.groupId 
        WHERE
            this_0_.ManagerId = 34
    );
```

So, I am getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is somthing like the following.

```
var list = session.QueryOver<Group>()
    .Where(x => x.Manager.Id == managerID)
    .Select(group=> group.Vehicle)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<Vehicle>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - got a solution, mostly. Minor inconvenience that I will ask another question on:

```
var sq = QueryOver.Of<VehicleGroup>(() => vehicleGroup)
    .JoinQueryOver<Manager>(vg => vg.Managers)
        .Where(man => man.Id == managerId)
    .JoinQueryOver<VehicleBase>(() => vehicleGroup.Vehicles)
        .Where(v => v.Id == item.VehicleId)
    .Select(vg => vg.Id)
    ;

var vp = Session.QueryOver<Summary>(() => item)
    .WithSubquery.WhereExists(sq)
    .Take(10)
    .List();
```

So, this works.  However, I had to add the map to Summary.VehicleId which is not what I wanted to do, but it'll do for now.